# Can someone expain the logic behind the following Django code?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a twitter clone(in python and django 1.10 using a tutorial on github. However I have passed through some ModelManager classes which I am failing to understande the logic especially in the first if statement.

```
class TweetManager(models.Manager):

    def retweet(self, user, parent_obj):
        if parent_obj.parent:
            og_parent = parent_obj.parent
        else:
            og_parent = parent_obj

        obj = self.model(
                parent = og_parent,
                user = user,
                content = parent_obj.content,
            )
        obj.save()

        return obj


class Tweet(models.Model):
    parent      = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content     = models.CharField(max_length=140, validators= [validate_content])
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = TweetManager()
```

Answer (score 3):

It prevents to make *chains* of parents. Imagine that you have a tweet `A` and that is retweeted, with a tweet `B`, then we do *not* want to create a tweet `C` with:

```
A <--- B <-x- C
```

We want both `B` and `C` to refer to the original parent `A`, like:

```
A <--- B
^
'-- C
```

So in case you want to retweet a `parent_obj`ect, it first looks if it is a retweet. If that is the case, it obtains the parent of that tweet. If the tweet has no parent, we can use that as parent.

If we do this each time, then checking one parent level is sufficient, since it can never happen that a tweet has a "grandparent".

Comment: I now get the hang of it. Thanks. Also what does this line of code really mean when inside the foreign key they write "self"  ```parent      = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)```

Comment: @Fnechz: `'self'` means it is a `ForeignKey` to the `Tweet` model.